# Convert a field of props data in my component

Tags: vue.js

I have a prop in my component:

```
props: {
  form_data: {
    type: Object,
    required: true
  },
...
```

and if in the `form_data` there is a field that is `discount`, it is a String.

but now in my component I want to bind the discount as Number.

```
<NumberInput v-model: form_data.discount />
```

but in the `<NumberInput>` this `form_data.discount` should be Number not String. In my way I will set another `computed` parma to convert the `form_data.discount` like this:

```
computed: {
  edit_form_data: {
    id: this.form_data.id,
    ...
    belong_product: this.form_data.belong_product
  }
}
```

then I use the `edit_form_data` to bind template.

But I think this is troublesome, not graceful. who can tell me whether there is other way to achieve this? such as like filter, or whatever.

Comment: i don't think that there is a good solution to your problem but to refactor your code to have a number in the formdata as well.

Comment: What `NumberInput` is that?

Comment: @acdcjunior [input number](https://www.iviewui.com/components/input-number)

Answer (score 0):

If in all the project `form_data.discount` can be used without problems as an integer you can convert it when you value it as follows:

`form_data.discount = Number(form_data.discount);`

otherwise do this conversion **inside** the component